# Bubble sort isn't working while sorting in ascending order

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort

I have created a program that seeks input from the users about a 5 digit number (char datatype used) and it bubble sorts it out based upon the ascending or descending order, depending upon the parameter set in if statement.

CASE 1 : if (a[j] < a[j+1])

- Input : 12345
- Desired output : 54321
- Output : 12345 - Works

CASE 2 : if (a[j] > a[j+1])

- Input : 54321
- Desired output : 12345
- Does not work.

Here's my code below :

```
int main()
{
    char a[6];
    int i, temp;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Enter a 5 digit number\n");
    scanf("%s", a);

    printf("You entered : %s\n", a);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 6 - 1 - i ; ++j )
        {
            if ( a[j] > a[j+1] )
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Bubble Sorted number : %s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it line by line. Something interesting happens when j is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inner for loop

```
    for ( j = 0 ; j < 6 - 1 - i ; ++j )
    {
        if ( a[j] > a[j+1] )
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

can overwrite the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string stored in the array `a`.

When in the outer loop the variable `i` is equal to `0` then you have actually the following inner loop

```
    for ( j = 0 ; j < 5 ; ++j )
    {
        if ( a[j] > a[j+1] )
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

In this case when `j` in the loop will be equal to `4` then the expression `a[j+1]` that is the same as `a[5]` will yield the terminating zero character that will be swapped with the character stored in the array element `a[4]`.

Rewrite the inner loop like

```
    for ( j = 1 ; j < 6 - 1 - i ; ++j )
    {
        if ( a[j-1] > a[j] )
        {
            temp = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. This worked for me :)